# Synonymize [opposite-word] to point to [antonyms]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Should the [opposite-word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposite-word) tag be made a synonym of the [antonyms](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonyms) master tag?
[opposite-word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposite-word) has 9 questions, and [antonyms](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonyms) has 35 questions.

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  I can't imagine any real distinction between the two.

Comment: I wonder if the `opposite-word` tag got created because a learner didn't know (or couldn't remember) the word "antonym".

Comment: Because [tag:antonyms] seems to be more commonly used, I think it should be the master tag.

Answer (score 5):

I think that is a great idea. *Antonym* is both a more popular tag, and more technical than *opposite-word*. Since this site caters to those who are not 100% proficient in English, a user could type in the easier-to-understand phrase, "opposite-word", and be redirected to the more technically correct word.